# How to get biggest correlations from columns and probability based on date and id (groupby), and assign it in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'm having a little trouble trying to get the Top3 correlations between sintoms and probability, and i need to groupby those things based on the same id and date. The problem is, i have more than 800k combinations, and in a for loop, it is consuming a LOT of time. Also, i need to save the Top 3 sintoms FOR EACH combination of id and date, in a list or something, to assign it to a new dataframe.

The example of dataframe i have, is something like this, but as i mentioned, more than 800k rows:

```
id    date     fever pain flu cough probability
1  2020-11-01    1    0    1    0       0.57
1  2020-11-02    0    1    1    1       0.44
2  2020-11-03    1    1    1    0       0.55
2  2020-11-03    0    1    1    1       0.67
3  2020-11-01    0    0    0    0         0
```

For the correlation i'm in need of `.corr()` from `pandas`.
And i know how correlation works, so, sometimes even if there is '1s' in the sintoms columns, sometimes there's no correlation detected between them and probability column. Remember, the correlation should be separeted between EACH id and date.

The desired df should be like this format (example):

```
id    date     fever pain flu cough probability  top3_sintoms
1  2020-11-01    1    0    1    0       0.57      Fever, Flu
1  2020-11-02    0    1    1    1       0.44      Cough, Flu, Pain
2  2020-11-03    1    1    1    0       0.55      Fever, Pain, Flu
2  2020-11-03    0    1    1    1       0.67      Pain, Flu, Cough
3  2020-11-01    0    0    0    0         0         None
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `dot`

```
s = df.loc[:,'fever':'cough']
df['new'] = s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
Out[235]: 
0         fever,flu
1    pain,flu,cough
2    fever,pain,flu
3    pain,flu,cough
4                  
dtype: object
```